# How to convert Pit/Dark Pit's drag-down nair into another hit

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

I've been playing a lot of Dark Pit in Smash Ultimate, and I've noticed that if I hit my opponent with my neutral aerial (nair) as I fall down, it drags my opponent with me.

***If*** I land on the stage while falling with my opponent, it always seems that he gets in the next hit. I've tried jabbing and grabbing as soon as I hit the ground and neither seems to beat out whatever my opponent happens to throw out.

*Is there any way to get in a guaranteed hit - or at least avoid my opponent's attack - when I fall on to the stage with nair?*

Comment: I believe Pit's lag when landing before finishing nair is greater than the opponent's hitstun. You might be able to catch them unaware, but I think they'll always be able to act a few frames before you. You could combo out of the last hit of nair if you don't fast fall it and I'm pretty sure drag down up-air can combo into grab or up-smash...That being said, this is all just from asking the Pit player at my local scene, which to me isn't enough evidence to write an answer for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-final hits of Pit's neutral aerial deal 0.7% damage with 100 knockback scaling, and the parts that hit downwards have 30 fixed knockback ([source](http://kuroganehammer.com/Ultimate/Pit)). This means it'll do somewhere in the range of 37.06-45.65 [knockback](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Knockback) and therefore 13-17 [hitstun](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Hitstun) (the variance is based on weight).

However, Pit's neutral aerial has a landing lag of 14, and his jab and grab don't hit until 5 and 6 respectively. So in the absolute best-case scenario, where you land the frame after you hit with the neutral aerial, the opponent can begin their next action 2 frames before your attack or grab comes out. Since perfection isn't guaranteed, the looping hits happen every 3 frames, and the opponent can land before you do, this'll get even worse.

So falling n-air with Pit isn't that followupable unless you're in a position where you will land significantly earlier than your opponent (and they still need to land before their aerial action comes out).